# Self Hosted Github Actions with local services (without containers)

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have this simple GitHub actions workflow on my self hosted Github Actions runner, running on MacOS:

```
name: "My Tests"
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: my-worker
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      ImageOS: macos1015
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.1 # Not needed with a .ruby-version file
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Create secrets.yml
        run: cp config/secrets.yml.sample config/secrets.yml
      - name: Run tests
        run: bundle exec rails db:prepare && bundle exec rspec
```

However, when I run it, it complains it cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:3128

I am guessing the worker creates a private network and isolates the environment from my current environment.

How do I expose my locally running service to the worker? - I understand the security implications but this is a small team and there is nothing sensitive on this port (MQTT server that just dumps the messages).

Answer (score 0):

DOH! - I had to change runs-on to:

```
    runs-on: self-hosted
```

Now it's running correctly on my machine, happy days!